# Suggestion needed on best approach to view DE import error logs

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

To check DE import errors, developer has to manually import the log file into a custom DE - which is time consuming. I’m planning on easing the process and have two ways in mind.

1. Use a file drop automation, import any file with name format "[UUID] Results [YYYYMMDD][4digit].txt" and send a mail to the developer with top 10 records from table. Problem is, in file drop automation, what should be given as selection criteria? Begins with.. ?
2. Use a cloud page to load file and view the content as a table in cloud page. Eg., Enter file name in input box 'file name' and click 'fetch' to draw a table with data in it. Problem is, there is no SFMC method available to read data from SFTP unless we use jsp/ servlet to connect to SFTP, read file etc.,.

File name example: 9A7568B8-53E1-4C48-9210-33CBCC1A2259 Results 202005230031.txt

Is there any other clean way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi, For the first option, can you try 'contains' 'Results.txt' for the filename . I think this should work.

Comment: You can create a subdirectory in the SFMC directory and have file drop activated with no naming convention which means it will run when any file is dropped there.